# ios9 on map move animate two buttons to switch places

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9

I have a map that auto locates the user. I have two buttons and when the screen is centered on the users location the standard order of buttons is in effect top: button 1, bottom: button 2. What I want is when the user slides the map to another location or uses the search that the top button becomes the bottom and vice versa.

I don't really have any idea where to start.

Thank you

Comment: Use the map scrollview delegate to catch map move events. Then use UIView animations to animate the buttons to your desired positions. Im at work right now, so i can|t make an example, sorry.

Comment: @OscarApeland Thank you, is it possible in the next few days to provide an example. I cannot seem to get it to work. I have been looking at the Apple Reference page and cannot seem to have any luck with the map scrollview delegate. Thank you

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:
Use this delegate method. Make sure to connect the delegate with your map and view controller. UIView animations should be pretty straight forward

Comment: mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:

Comment: @OscarApeland i'm sorry to be such a bother, but ive literally copied and pasted apple's example and it doesn't work

Comment: and if i replace bool with true it gives me an error that it expects a , but when i add it it wants me to add another and another